# Unable to open Portal 2 Authoring tools

Tags: portal-2

This is really confusing me.
So I have a Microsoft Windows laptop, and I've played Portal 1 and 2 for AGES. I recently heard about Hammer, and I found out that the place to use it is on the Authoring tools, but every time I have tried to open and use it, it won't launch. Like, not at all! I get no messages about what the issue is, or if there's an error. It just will register me opening it and say 'running' for like 4 seconds before vanishing and stopping completely.

Comment: Try re-downloading Portal 2 (the game, not the authoring tools), run the game at least once, then try opening the authoring tools again.

Comment: Can you please explain what "Hammer" is? I guess you can understand that it's hard to google.

Comment: @Fabian _Valve Hammer Editor_ is the official map editor for Source-engine games.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try opening them manually from the installation directory of the authoring tools.